# Adding animation to a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have written simple plugin that draws a pie chart by creating canvas and filling in an arc. The basic structure is:

```
    $.fn.mychart = function(options) { 
      var settings = $.extend...;  // various user settings 

      return this.each(function() {
        var element = this;
        draw(element, settings.startRadians, settings.endRadians,...);
      })
   };

   var draw = function(element, startRadians, endRadians, ...) {
     // Draw implementation
   };
```

Inside of draw(), I create a canvas as a child of element and draw an arc. This works perfectly fine.

Now I want to animate the arc drawing and configure it with a "delay" value so I can control how fast/slow the arc fills.

What is the proper jquery plugin "way" to add animation to the draw() function?
Thanks!

Comment: It really depends what you are animating. It’s a bit difficult to conceptualize what kind of animation do you need—perhaps some kind of illustration or link to a pre-existing example will help. For expanded possibilities to animate charts like that, I will recommend using a library that already has those features built in, such as d3.js, so you don’t spend too much time reinventing the wheel :)

Answer (score -1):

That is an easy one.

Please checkout [jquery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Please avoid using link-only answers—otherwise, stick to posting comments. Perhaps include a code snippet as a proof-of-concept example.